# How can I add new UI to a Vaadin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, vaadin

I do not really know how can I add a new page to a Vaadin project. As an experiment I renamed one page:

I renamed this:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
```

To:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/blabla1", asyncSupported = true)
```

However, I want a new page:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/blabla2", asyncSupported = true)
```

Unfortunatley, when I renamed the first, I get this message in Chrome:

> failed to load bootstrap javascript vaadin

How do I add a second web page, given that the above renaming of the example seems to be failing?

Comment: In vaadin you don't use the page / url based navigation. It's a application you start and then inside this application you modify the UI. No need for different URL's

Comment: @andré-schild Thank you very much. But then I have another question. Which pattern do you use to implement e.g. two functions in the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

André´s answer is not entirely correct. While simple Vaadin applications can behave like single page applications where you only modify contents of UI without changing url, applications are usually more complex than that and require a different approach.

Signgle page applications with single url have a several disadvantages. Application usually consists of many parts and states and normally those have their own urls. User can navigate directly to desired component or state, bookmark it to visit it directly later, can use back and froward buttons etc.

In Vaadin this is achieved throug Navigator. Each UI consists of number of Views. Navigator is then used to navigate between views. Each view has its unique url represented by URL fragment, so users can navigate there, bookmart it etc.

You can read detailed tutorial about navigation [here in book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html).

> Plain Vaadin applications do not have normal web page navigation as
>   they usually run on a single page, as all Ajax applications do. Quite
>   commonly, however, applications have different views between which the
>   user should be able to navigate. The Navigator in Vaadin can be used
>   for most cases of navigation. Views managed by the navigator
>   automatically get a distinct URI fragment, which can be used to be
>   able to bookmark the views and their states and to go back and forward
>   in the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class example for using "Navigator" in Vaadin. First create a simple navigator object and use it in the layout to display the views.

```js
public class NavigationtestUI extends UI {
  @Override
    public void init(VaadinRequest request) {

  // Create Navigator, use the UI content layout to display the views
  Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, getContent());

 // Add some Views
  navigator.addView(MainView.NAME, new MainView()); // no fragment

 // #count will be a new instance each time we navigate to it, counts:
 navigator.addView(CountView.NAME, CountView.class);

 // Navigate to view
 navigator.navigate();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment based URLs are indeed something that should be favoured. You can also serve different Vaadin UI's to different URLs (without fragment) by providing a [custom UI provider](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.lifecycle.html#application.lifecycle.ui.uiprovider).

And if you use either [Vaadin CDI](https://vaadin.com/addon/vaadin-cdi) or [Vaadin Spring](https://vaadin.com/addon/vaadin-spring) (and your really should use either of those), you can also map UIs to different URLS simply by providing the last part of the url as a parameter to the annotation.